# Tor consensus store location

Tags: directory

Where Tor client stores the consensus?

It appears ./tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/state only contains guard nodes data not other nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tor Browser downloads the microdescriptor consensus, which you can find at `Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/cached-microdesc-consensus`.